# How to retrieve a video from an HTML file using wget

Tags: bash, scripting, wget

I am trying to download some videos from a website using `wget`. I used the syntax of wget.
The command is as follows:

```
wget https://some_link/download.mp4?lecture_id=5
```

The problem is that it is downloading an `HTML` file. However, when I right click on this link in the website and select `Save target as`, I get the video file which I want to save. Similarily, when I click on the link, it shows a video file that can be saved or opened.

I tried the following command but to no avail:-

```
wget -O vid.mp4 https://some_link/download.mp4?lecture_id=5
```

It created a `.mp4` file but it didn't have any video in it. The size of this file was also equal to the size of the `HTML` file that was created before.

Comment: you might try parsing the html in order to find the direct url of the requested video source. Alternatively you might try investigating the HTTP headers when opening the html in your browser. By doing that you might also get the direct url of the video source.
Anyway, if you posted the actual url to lectures it might be easier to help.

Comment: Could you give any pointers on how to proceed with that?

Comment: I think you asked this question before but I can't find it now. I was trying to help you on that question!

Comment: Taking the HTTP headers approach: You need to open up a web console in your browser (e.g. in firefox menu->web developers->show tools and go to the console tab). You should now be able to see all the "messages" being exchanged between the client (browser) and the server. Those so called http headers might for example look like this: GET name/of/resource/video.mp4 HTTP/1.1. One of these ressources should be the video file you are looking for.
Alternatively you can just look up: How to display http headers

Comment: @RobinGreen I am sure you were. I found that even if I removed my user-name and password, the link worked then also. I guess it wasn't the problem I thought I had. If I would I have changed that same question, I would have ran into a risk of attracting criticism of the stackoverflow admins ( I have faced this situation before ). I am sorry to take such a step.

Comment: @feaDawn Thanks for the advice. Worked perfectly. There is, however, one problem. The http header is explicitly showing the name of the video. Can I extend this approach to download multiple files?

Comment: Hmm, if the video resource's name is indeed different every time (and in a way that is not easily reconstructable [like an increasing number]), the best way I see right now, is downloading the html file using wget and then extracting the video's url using regex and afterwards downloading the target file using wget, again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `wget` with parameters to download files recursively (you can download html page with all resources needed by this page like graphics).

Alternatively you can download HTML page via `wget`, then look for the mp4 file using `grep` with regular expression and then again use `wget` do download only mp4 file.